# Why does SDL program not show BMP picture?

Tags: c++, sdl

I've got following code from [Lazy](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/index2.php):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Surface *hello = NULL;
    SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE);

    hello = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(hello, NULL, screen, NULL);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    SDL_FreeSurface(hello);

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

From time to time the picture is shown, but most of time it's just a black window (with slim string of this picture). And I've got the BMP file with name "hello.bmp" in the same directory. 
PS.I've got ArchLinux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before displaying your image you should convert it to a format compatible to the video mode you selected.
Therefore you should implement something like this:

```
SDL_Surface *imagef;
imagef = SDL_DisplayFormat(image);
```

Before bliting your BMP and use `imagef` for all of your operations.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. But does it happen. There's no sign of it in tutorial.

Comment: I didn't know about that tutorial. I answered basing on my knowledge. What do you mean by 'does it happen'? And, if my answer is what you were looking for, would you accept it, please?

Comment: Of course, no problem) But I don't understand why it works without formatting on most of cases (I've googled it and seen a lot of answers on similar question like that: "It works properly on my computer").

Comment: I don't know it exactly. I think - although it's just my bet - that since SDL_DisplayFormat copies information (such as pixel format) from the framebuffer to the new surface, and those are based to the monitor being used, it's a hardware dependent matter. As I don't know how SDL functions fill in the members of the pixel format struct (and color as well), I can't say if sometimes SDL_LoadBMP converts the BMP to a surface somewhat compatible with the monitor (without need to convert it). I tried to keep it simple as I can.

Comment: You're welcome. Yet, consider the fact it's just my bet, don't take it for granted.